# Is it possible to have ERC20 token (A) own other ERC20 tokens (X, Y, Z)

Tags: solidity, ether, erc-20

I'm building a DAPP, where a user has one 'parent' ERC20 token and several other 'child' ERC20 tokens.

So what I want is .... To have a parent token A, and that token owns the tokens X, Y and Z.

In my DAPP, the parent does not always own the same child tokens. Child tokens are dynamic in size and type.

The reason being, I want to be able transfer 'ownership' of all the tokens in 1 transaction, by simply transferring token A from one address to another.

Is this possible?

I have been looking into Proxy Contracts, but I'm not sure if this would work. I was wondering if anybody has done something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token ownerships are simply an entry in the token contract about which address owns how many tokens. The address can be either an EOA (Externally Owned Address, a wallet) or a contract address - it doesn't make any difference.

But before you send tokens to your contract address make sure the contract has all the required functionality to handle the tokens. If the contract doesn't have the required functionality it will just have the tokens forever with no way of transferring them onwards anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not using the ERC20 standard, theres a standard for that, ERC998. I suggest you read about it. The thing @Lauri answered is unrelated to what you were asking i believe (unless i got your question wrong)